# Notification content extension setup

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, usernotifications, unnotificationserviceextension

I've set up a Notification Content Extension for my app, but it's not called on a remote push. I've read the apple dev guide below to the letter, and I've set up everything as it says.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications?language=objc

I've looked over the common issues (setting proper deployment target and setting category identifier from backend and in the .plist). I've also tried setting App Transport Security Settings to allow arbitrary loads.

[info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMmMa.png)

What actually happens is that the Notification Service Extension gets called instead.

Do I need to do some routing so that the Service extension isn't called, or do I need to redirect from Service extension to Content extension? Is it even possible to use both simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I have an app with multiple targets, and the Content Extension had only been added as an embedded binary for one of the targets.